# implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener { api 23 to api 15 example?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this code:

```
 public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
 RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {
```

and this:

```
    //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
```

OnScrollChangeListener and setOnScrollChangeListener do not work in API below 23.

To work on api 15, for example, I read in another post to use `addOnScrollListener` instead. The problem is when I change OnScrollChangeListener to addOnScrollListener it gives me an `Cannot resolve symbol`.

My question is, how can I change the code above to work in API below 23?

Answer (score 2):

This is for below than 23

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);


                }
@Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        // your code
    }
        });
```

You can use it with this.You are getting this error because RecyclerView.OnScrollListener is a class not an interface.So you cannot implement it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `addOnScrollListener` and it's working fine with the support library 24.2.0.

I'm overriding the two methods `onScrollStateChanged` and `onScrolled`:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        // your code
    }
});
```